# How to "quickly" solve the following linear system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of equation $(S)$, where $m$ is a parameter in $\mathbb{R}$
$$ (S)
\begin{cases}
(m-1)x+my+z=1\\
mx+2y+3z=3\\
(m+1)x+my+(m-1)z=m-1
\end{cases}
$$
I've tried solving it using the Gauss pivot method but it is very long and takes a lot of calculation.
Is there any other simpler way to find the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ (S)
\begin{cases}
(m-1)x+my+z=1\\
mx+2y+3z=3\\
(m+1)x+my+(m-1)z=m-1
\end{cases}
$$

No need  for heavy calculus. Simple inspection  obviously gives 
$$\begin{cases} x=0 \\ y=0 \\ z=1 \end{cases}$$

NOTE :

The above result is true any value of $m$.

But if $\quad\left|\left|\begin{matrix}
m-1 & m & 1 \\
m & 2 & 3 \\
m+1 & m & m-1
\end{matrix}\right|\right|
=m^2(4-m)=0\quad$ ,

that is if $m=0$ or $m=4$ , the three equations are not linearly independent.

Then they are an infinity of solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Solving a $3 \times 3$ just takes a certain amount of work.  Here subtracting the first from the third gives $$2x+(m-2)z=m-2$$
and adding the first and third gives $$2mx + 2my + mz=m$$
If $m \neq 0$ you can divide it out.  If $m=0$ you will be an equation short.